# Change center point and size with the help of the Matrix in Unity

Tags: unity, matrix, vertex, scale, pivot

Let us suppose I have an array of `Vector3`, it contains vertices. 
Now I want to scale the vertices and/or change the center point of the texture (move texture relatively).

I have a `Vector3` which is a new center point and I have a `Vector3` which is vector for scaling along x, y and z.

How can I construct a needed matrix in Unity?

I am very new to all this, so, please, in case of any misunderstanding ask me about it.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint3x4.html) is what I was able to find on my own. The problem with it, though, is that I can not infer what I need from it. I need a little bit more peculiar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a matrix for this at all?

```
Vector3 ScaleAndShiftVector(Vector3 v, Vector3 shift, Vector3 scale) {
    return Vector3.Scale(v, scale) + shift;
}
```

You could do this with a matrix,

```
var matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(shift, Quaternion.identity, scale);
var transformed = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(v);
```

but that does more calculations than you need, since it's accounting for rotation too which you're not using.

Comment: It does not work somehow. I after modifying the vertex of the texture in this way the image does not change its size.

Comment: Textures don't have vertices. Meshes do. Are you manipulating the positions of a mesh's vertices, or its texture coordinates, or something else? Show your code in your question and we can help you find the error.